# Find objects that reference 2 tables in a big GeneXus KB

Tags: genexus

I have a KB with many tables and many objects.
I need a way to find all objects that use 2 system tables and perform a join between them.
Something like **(Objects that use TABLE1) INTERSECTION (Objects that use TABLE2)**.
Can it be done from the GeneXus IDE?